# Signalr connection is closing on web garden with 404 code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0, stackexchange.redis

A signalr API (.NET 6) is hosted on IIS with "web garden" mode. Client frequently closes a connection with the following message: "*System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."*

When IIS config is changed not to use webgarden (max worker processes is set to 1) - error does not occur.
I have read that redis backplane would be a solution in such case (webgarden) but inlcuding it in my project did not help - the same error message occurs in same scenarios.

Here is my sample code from the Startup:

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            })
            .AddHubOptions<MyHub>(options =>
            {
                options.AddFilter<MyFilter>();
            })
            .AddNewtonsoftJsonProtocol()
            .AddStackExchangeRedis(o =>
            {
                o.ConnectionFactory = async writer =>
                {
                    var config = new ConfigurationOptions
                    {
                        AbortOnConnectFail = false
                    };
                    config.EndPoints.Add(IP_ADDR, PORT_NO);
                    config.DefaultDatabase = DEFAULT_DB;
                    var connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync(config, writer);
                    connection.ConnectionFailed += (_, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connection to Redis failed.");
                    };

                    if (!connection.IsConnected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Did not connect to Redis.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Redis.");
                    }                       

                    return connection;
                };
            });
```

Did I miss somethig in my code? Or maybe it is about IIS configuration?

Comment: Could you please share, your `Hub` and `client` version? Have you enable [`Client affinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing#step-3---configure-client-affinity) in IIS manager? In addition, what's your OS and version?could you please confirm if there is any `connection latency`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Hub version is: _Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60_. Client version is: _Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60_. Client OS is _Win10_. Server OS is _Win Server 2012 R2_ . Thhere is no connection latency configured.

Comment: Have you `Configured client affinity` on ARR module in IIS?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Is client affinity a part of the server farm configuration? I do not have any server farm configured on the server.

Comment: For  [`redis backplane `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-7.0#redis-backplane) we ought to consider [`these pre-requisite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-a-redis-backplane) if there is any connenction failure incident reported.